# A way to set up credentials to package feed [YOCTO]

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I can enable package-manager by writing in build/conf/local.conf

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dnf"
```

Sign packages and enable the target to use them

```
INHERIT += "sign_rpm"
RPM_GPG_NAME = "61A0ADBADFC08CCF"
RPM_GPG_PASSPHRASE = "hardcore_password"
```

Add packages URI

```
PACKAGE_FEED_URIS = "https://rpms.myserver.com/"
```

Adding the last command produces the following file on the target image

```
/etc/yum.repos/oe-remote-rpm.repo
```

The file contains the given URI.
I wonder how I can put credentials to the repository inside this file. Can it be done from conf.local?
Or should I prepare a recipe with a file like this:

```
name= My RPM Server
baseurl=https://rpms.myserver.com
username=rpmtaker
password=hardcore_password
enabled=1
gpgcheck = 1
```

and copy this file to /etc/yum.repos/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have come up with so far is to place in config/local.conf:

```
PACKAGE_FEED_URIS ="https://login:password@my.repo.com/"
```